# Retrieving the last record in each group, older than given time

Tags: mysql

As in this question: [Retrieving the last record in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group), I want to query the latest entries of each group.

In difference to the linked question, I also want to add a criteria for the maximum time.

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT m1.*
FROM messages m1
LEFT JOIN messages m2
ON (
    m1.name = m2.name AND
    m1.id < m2.id AND
    m2.time <= nnnnnnn
)
WHERE m2.id IS NULL
AND m1.time <= nnnnnnn;
```

I am not sure if this is 100% correct, Is there a better solution? Maybe without the duplicate `time <= nnnnnnn` condition?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the `where` clause instead:

```
select m.*
from messages m
where m.id = (select m2.id
              from messages m2
              where m2.name = m.name and
                    m2.time <= nnnn
              order by m2.time desc
              limit 1
             )
```

Comment: This gives me a single message (`limit 1`). I need the latest messages of each group

Comment: @schlimpf . . . This is a correlated subquery.  It is going to return one value for each group.  The performance will be much improved if you have an index on `messages(name, time)` or `message(name, time, id)`.

Comment: and avoid using a correlated subquery

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for. last-n-per-group-less-than-x

```
 SELECT m1.*
    FROM messages m1
    LEFT JOIN messages m2 ON (
        m2.name = m1.name AND
        IF(m2.date < 'nnnnnnn',m2.date > m1.date, m1.date > 'nnnnnnn')) 
    WHERE m2.idIS NULL
```